# Generate vector tiles for dynamic data

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, tippecanoe

I am having around million features stored in PostgreSQl table (with PostGIS extension).

I can generate vector tiles by performing below steps

1. Generate GeoJSON  from PG table using GDAL
2. Generate vector files in folder format using tippecanoe
3. Sync the features to S3

Then using Mapbox gl js layer is rendered in map

Now we are trying to add editing functionality. so that users can add, edit or delete features.

Is there a way to efficiently generate vector tiles with new created features using tippecanoe and keep the vector tiles up to date?

Is tippecanoe is right tool for this job?

Comment: Since the advantage of vector tiles is the caching on the client I would have thought that there was no good way to do editing and vector tiles, look at WFS-T instead

Comment: wfs-t is a non starter for millions of features... because map cannot be rendered while being zoomed out...

just looking for ways to retile for the features affected (i can pass the extent as input)